# exec bash file with putty

Tags: windows, bash, ssh

I'm trying to execute a bash file with putty/plink but gives me an error.

On windows Ive got this batch:

```
E:\putty\plink.exe user@link -pw password -m E:\folder\test.sh
```

on bash file Ive got this:

```
#!/bin/bash
vtoff
vtadmin check connector /PCS/ConnectionModels/Arbor/
```

and the error:

```
C:\folder>e:\folder\test.bat
C:\folder>e:\putty\plink.exe user@link -pw password -m e:\folder\test.sh
ksh[4]: vtoff:  not found
ksh[5]: vtadmin:  not found

C:\folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.66/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage) says that `-m` specifies that it should "read remote command(s) from file".

Since `#!/bin/bash` isn't a command, and your error message references `ksh`, it's pretty clear that bash is nowhere to be found in this question!

As for your actual error message, it seems that the commands aren't found, probably because they're not in your `PATH`.

Comment: i found out that OS at the server is sun and not linux, could it be the reason for the commands dont run?

Comment: The commands are run, as evidenced by the error message you're getting. As I said, they aren't found, probably because they're not in your `PATH`.